# HTC u11 didn't any reaction to press button ony to see the computer the com port and phone flash

Tags: recovery-mode, usb-connection-mode, system, system-error, htc-u11

I'm bought the HTC u11 is the dead OS. The other owner did something with the system. The phone is see the computer the com port and the phone flashing Red lights. I'm try to charging battery but didn't solve it.The phone only start to edl mode.

Please help with any ideas.

Comment: Did you know that the software was defect when buying the device? If not return the device and get your money back. Otherwise I would try to install a HTC u11 factory/RUU image as described here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=72425210&postcount=3

Comment: Thanks for writing help just unfortunately it doesn't work can't recognize the phone. In response to your request, I use the phone as a part of the original. Now I'm trying to make it work for this motherboard as well.